# How to modify RegisterForm in flask security to add the values from a field to different table

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

I have added a field to the RegisterForm of flask security and the field is being rendered on the register page. The modified form is as follows-

```
class Registerform_roles(RegisterForm):
    role = SelectField(label="Role", \
                    validators=[
                        validators.data_required(),
                        unique_identity_attribute
                    ],\
                    choices=['a','b','c']
                )
```

I want the values from this field to be saved to a different table in the datastore instead of the User table whenever the form is submitted. I wasn't able to find the part of the code that handles the post request from the register page. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to set up a signal handler for 'user_registered' - that will receive the entire form as well as the User that was just registered.

Comment: can you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#signals